# Pass function properties through one function? Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find out the best way in order to establish that the game is over.

I have my gameover() function

```
    function gameover(chk, scoreOne, scoreTwo) {
        if (chk === true) {
            // Game is over
            // Show scoreOne
            // Show scoreTwo
        }
    }
```

It is going to need 3 variables.

```
        } else if(validCurrQuestion.length == 2){
            // Clears validCurrQuestion so that it can run to the next question
            validCurrQuestion.splice(0,validCurrQuestion.length);
            validQuestions.shift();
            if (validQuestions.length > 0) {
              dataRequest();  
            } else {
                checker = true;
            }

        }

        socket.on("player one", function(data) {
            console.log(data.pScore + "THIS IS WORKING");
            score = data.pScore;
            console.log("THIS IS PLAYER TWO" + data.pNameTwo);
            io.sockets.emit("player ones score", {p1Score: score});
        });

        socket.on("player two", function(data) {
            console.log(data.pScore + "THIS IS WORKING");
            score = data.pScore;
            io.sockets.emit("player twos score", {p2Score: score});
        });
```

Those 3 values are checker, scoreP1 and scoreP2. Is there a way to get each of those values through to the gameover function?

Comment: I think you'll need to clean up your example code before we can be of help!

Comment: Create object that stores game state. Also...sure seems like socket should pass back both scores if it's a 2 player game

Comment: @charlietfl thats why I wanted to create the game over function to have a way of sending both scores at the same time. Because currently what player one and player two socket events are doing is sending the other player scores to the other person. So to make it easier I wanted them in one place so i can display them at the same time. I guess what I could also do is just sock emit the scores again in the game over function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so a couple things.

I think the direct answer is just to have a variable that holds the scores of the players that is in the same scope of your "checker" variable.

```
var checker = false, 
     scores={
        p1:0,
        p2:0
    };
```

Then when you receive an update from the sockets callback, you modify this variable

```
scores.p1 = data.pScore;
```

So when you call gameover, it looks like this :

```
gameover(checked, scores.p1, scores.p2);
```

--- End of Direct Answer ---

**Other Observations and Advice**

I'm not sure why you need the chk parameter in your gameover function because you should just call gameover directly (and remove the if statement inside gameover). I could see where knowing "if the game is over" might be useful to know for other uses. You could rename checked to "isGameover" and then set that variable to true inside your gameover function. The other thing I'm not sure about is making sure that both players have the gameover happen at the same time. You will probably need to have a sockets callback handler and emit  to communicate to each client that the game is over to make sure that the game ends the same way for both players.

Comment: Thanks to you I was able to remove two of those functions and only make use of my objects. Thank you good sir.